# multi-item responsive carousel for angular material

Tags: angularjs, slider, carousel, responsive, angularjs-material

I'm trying to create a multi item responsive slider in AngularJS. I'm familiar with Owl Carousel (https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/) and Slick Slider (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), but both use jQuery and I want something without jQuery.

Please suggest any directives or sliders, or any other easy way to do it.

I want to achieve the following output:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: have you implemented this one ?

Answer (score 5):

I have created on multi item carousal that is available on [github](https://github.com/lijoos/angular-carousal)

You can see demo [here](https://angular-carousal.firebaseapp.com/)

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

@William:

You can use [angular carousel](https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel) which is pretty much similar of owl carousel.

Here is the [link](http://revolunet.github.io/angular-carousel/) for its demo.

Hope this will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but i think the carousel you mentioned is not multi item

Comment: @WilliamScott: Yes, that is not for multi item. But see what I found out. Somebody made it for multi item using little customisation. Check this once if it will be helpful for you  http://plnkr.co/edit/oVRYCfaMeRW5a54nzmem?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for a simple solution and found this one:

https://github.com/lifelynl/angular-carousel

As promised, it's simple and generic, and it also works like Owl Carousel or bxSlider, you can put anything inside the slides.